# Get API response time in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

I'm trying to find out how much will adding another font (partially) affect the speed of my website. This is what I've tried.

```
<script>
  var currentTime = new Date();
</script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto|Playfair+Display" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy&text=Stevi">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400i&text=adeGhiJjLlmnoRrsVvzć">
<script>
  var newDate = new Date();
  console.log(newDate - currentTime);
</script>
```

Is this legal? I mean, is what am I getting really the time it took to get responses from all three requests?

Comment: Don't do this, use Developer Tools in your browser, which are _far more informative_. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/ and https://developer.mozilla.org/son/docs/Tools/Performance Like, "get responses" is probably not what you care about as much as _DOM parsing_ and _render blocking_ (which CSS is). But there are a myriad of techniques to analyze and improve performance.

Comment: Definitely use developer tools.  You can see how long each asset takes to load in the network section.

Comment: Make dev tools your friend

Comment: @msanford - the impulse isn't bad. While developer tools is awesome and all that, it doesn't give you any sense of what your users are experiencing on their networks. Getting data like this so that you can build a profile of your average and outlier users is helpful, although this particular implementation is naive.

Comment: @JDB Yes, it absolutely does. Perceived performance with throttling, such as can be analyzed with Lighthouse, is powerful. Also I expanded my comment to be more informative and less trite. This approach is not _worthless_, but it is, as you said, naive and _less informative_ than my suggested alternative. That's all.

Comment: @msanford - again... throttling won't give you any data about your *actual users*. Without knowing more about your users, you won't know what kinds of optimizations make sense.

Comment: @JDB Agreed, but still, this is _not informative_ because it only times downloading the asset, which is far from even the most relevant perceived performance metric.

Comment: You are currently using  CDN and you can't calculate exact time. plus dev tools you can also use jquery page load function `$(window).load(function() {});` and check it a few times.

Comment: @msanford - totally agree, which is why this is a naive solution.

Comment: Ah... here it is... [Real User Monitoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_user_monitoring). Not sure if this is what the OP is trying to accomplish, but building your own from scratch is probably not the best idea given the obvious lack of experience with JS. If you are just trying to measure performance yourself, then DevTools all the way.